# Sort a list by elements of another list

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I know there are a plenty of other questions here which appear to be similar, however I did not found anything which could give me a hint.

I have two lists:

```
list1 = {{A, 12}, {B, 10}, {C, 4}}; (*ordered according to the second column*)
list2 = {{B, 5}, {A, 4}, {C, 1}};   (*ordered according to the second column*)
```

Now I want to sort `list2`according to the `list1`-order so the output should be:

```
(* {{A, 4}, {B, 5}, {C, 1}} *)
```

Comment: to be more specific `list2`should be sorted according to the first column of `list1`

Comment: Is there a better example to show what you want?  Doesn't `Sort[list2]` give the desired output?

Comment: `list2[[OrderingBy[list1, -#[[2]] &]]]` in the next release...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Permute[list2, FindPermutation[ list2[[All,1]] , list1[[All,1]] ] ]
```

> {{A, 4}, {B, 5}, {C, 1}}

Comment: Actually, I like your solution much better than mine. By the way, when I found out that my former solution was incorrect, I also realized that your solution should better be `Permute[list2, FindPermutation[list2[[All, 1]], list1[[All, 1]]]]`.

Comment: Doh...fixed it. Both ways give the same answer, which leads to sloppy debugging.

Answer (score 7):

```
list1 = {{A, 12}, {B, 10}, {C, 4}, {D, 2}};
list2 = {{A, 4}, {D, 11}, {B, 5}, {C, 1}};

idx = Lookup[
   AssociationThread[list1[[All, 1]] -> Range[Length[list1]]],
   list2[[All, 1]]
   ];
result = list2;
result[[idx]] = list2;
result
```

> {{A, 4}, {B, 5}, {C, 1}, {D, 11}}

Comment: works well with the example lists. However, something goes wrong when I use other lists with Strings in the first columns instead of `A`, `B`and `C`....

Answer (score 6):

ugly but fast:

```
list2[[Ordering[list2[[All, 1]]][[Ordering[Ordering[list1[[All, 1]]]]]]]]
```

> {{A, 4}, {B, 5}, {C, 1}}

even faster:

```
result = list2;
result[[Ordering[list1[[All, 1]]]]] = SortBy[list2, First];
result
```

> {{A, 4}, {B, 5}, {C, 1}}

### benchmarks

```
s = 10^7;
list1 = Transpose[{PermutationList@RandomPermutation[s],
                   RandomInteger[{0, 10}, s]}];
list2 = Transpose[{PermutationList@RandomPermutation[s],
                   RandomInteger[{0, 10}, s]}];

(* my first solution *)
result1 = list2[[Ordering[list2[[All, 1]]][[Ordering[Ordering[list1[[All, 1]]]]]]]]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 8.6416 *)

(* my second solution *)
result2 = Module[{L},
  L = list2;
  L[[Ordering[list1[[All, 1]]]]] = SortBy[list2, First];
  L]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 6.89593 *)

(* MikeY's solution *)
result3 = Permute[list2, FindPermutation[list2[[All, 1]], list1[[All, 1]]]]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 15.808 *)

(* Henrik Schumacher's solution *)
result4 = Module[{idx, L},
  idx = Lookup[AssociationThread[list1[[All, 1]] -> Range[Length[list1]]], list2[[All, 1]]];
  L = list2;
  L[[idx]] = list2;
  L]; //AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 31.7412 *)

(* make sure all methods agree *)
result1 == result2 == result3 == result4
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. I started down the `Ordering` road, but went for parsimony of expression. Mild bummer that it is at least twice as slow as the best method.

Answer (score 2):

```
p = {{a, 12}, {b, 10}, {c, 4}};

q = {{b, 5}, {a, 4}, {c, 1}};

n = Length[p];
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[Last /@ Sort[q] &, p, Table[{i, 2}, {i, n}]]
```

{{a, 4}, {b, 5}, {c, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = {{a, 12}, {b, 10}, {c, 4}};

l2 = {{b, 5}, {a, 4}, {c, 1}};
```

Using `OrderingBy` and `RotateLeft`:

```
l2[[RotateLeft@OrderingBy[l1, Last]]]

(*{{a, 4}, {b, 5}, {c, 1}}*)
```